# Ubuntu 14.04 - How do I play an ogg file on shutdown with a script?

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04, shutdown, pulseaudio

So, I'm attempting to have a script play a short ogg file on shutdown/restart but I seem to be having some sort of trouble actually getting it to work. Right now, I have the script in init.d and have symbolic links in rc0.d and rc6.d that all seem to work when manually executed. The script and the links all start with "K99" because the system supposedly proceeds alphabetically through the list and K99 should make it execute at the correct time. (I've tried other things, like K00, K50 and the "S" variations because I saw some other scripts with that; but they didn't seem to change anything.)

```html
#!/bin/sh
## play shutdown sound

pulseaudio --start
echo -e "Shutdown sound script."
/usr/bin/play /home/username/Downloads/sound_file.ogg
sleep 3
```

The script is pretty simple I think. The ogg file and the script are both at 755 permissions. The file is only about 3s long, so I don't think that's a problem either. Originally, it seemed as if the script wasn't working at all so I added the sleep command. It seems to take about three seconds longer to shut down now, so I think the script IS running, but I have a feeling that Ubuntu is perhaps killing the audio daemon (if there is one?) before the script goes off, but I'm not sure. I've spent a few days trying to figure this seemingly simple thing out. Any ideas?

Sorry if this ends up being trivial, I'm a bit of a novice with Ubuntu system things. (Though I'd be fine with a simple fix! :) )

**UPDATE**
It works as it should now! After some searching about why the sound might be playing multiple times and especially on startup, I learned a bit more about the upstart system. It looks through the etc/init/ directory and runs the scripts in there on start up. I remembered that I had experimented by putting an upstart script there when the sound was still not playing at all. Apparently I had forgotten to remove it and it was executing on all run levels thus leading to the double shutdown and startup instances. Now it's gone and all is as it should be. (Although now that I've fixed it, I'm a bit sick of hearing the sound and might have to find a new one, lol.) Thanks for the help, all.

**TL;DR:** Put a script in init.d and symbolically link to etc/rc0.d (and etc/rc6.d if you want it on reboot too). If it plays multiple times, you've probably got a duplicate somewhere it shouldn't be.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I don't think so. What's the best way to check that, to be sure?

Comment: @MichaelPetch That didn't return anything. (Same to edit)

Comment: @MichaelPetch I think that mpg123 is having issue with the ogg file. It gives this message "Note: Illegal Audio-MPEG-Header 0x00000000 at offset 25767"

Comment: @MichaelPetch For bell.ogg: "Note: Illegal Audio-MPEG-Header 0x00000000 at offset 5012." (It might also be useful to note that I originally tried to replace the shutdown sound here with the new one, but neither ever played, new or old, so I moved to the script solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To execute a script at shutdown**

- Put your script in /etc/rc0.d
- Make it executable (`sudo chmod +x script.sh`)
- Note: The scripts in this directory are executed in alphabetical
  order

**PulseAudio**

PulseAudio is a sound server. It allows you to do advanced operations on your sound data as it passes between your application and your hardware.

Start PulseAudio at the begging of your script:

```
pulseaudio --start
```

**Note:** You must try/use this commands in your script because starting audio daemon and playing your ogg file is just a matter of time.

Comment: runlevel 6 is reboot, not shutdown.

Comment: @JGaines Have you ever tried shutdown with 30 seconds delay: `/sbin/shutdown -h -t 30`

Comment: @MehmetMertYidiran Just did. Used "now" instead of "-t 30" (hope that doesn't matter). I didn't see any change in the shutdown process.

Comment: @JGaines It matters actually :) with "-t 30" the computer will shutdown with 30 seconds delay. In the meantime, your script can be executed but I'm not sure. Actually as you can see "shutdown" program is a binary program. Maybe, this could be an obstacle for you.

Comment: @MehmetMertYidran I tried it again "shutdown -h 1" which gave it a 1 min delay, it didn't like the -t flag. It didn't seem to change things with this run either.

Comment: @MehmetMertYidran When I manually run the script now it outputs and error at the beginning "E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed." but the sound clip plays as normal. I also get this message when I run "pulseaudio -D" at the command line as well. Will check if there is a different result on shutdown now...

Comment: @JGaines I fixed my answer, `pulseaudio --start` should work. This is my last attempt :) I don't have more ideas.

Comment: @MehmetMertYidran So, that made the sound play; however, it is playing the sound 1-3 times it seems and again on startup. I removed the link in my rc6.d thinking that may be why it plays at the startup, but it still plays. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JGaines Which command that I suggest made the sound play? You should locate your script in `/etc/rc0.d` instead of `/etc/rc6.d`. I think in `/etc/rc0.d` it will not play the sound on startup. But I don't have any idea about 1-3 times playing. Finally, can you make my answer as accepted and maybe an upvote will be good :)

Comment: @MehmetMertYidiran Both "pulseaudio -D" and "pulseaudio --start" play the sound, but both play it twice on shutdown and once on startup. Removing from rc6.d didn't change this. Still this puts me on the right path. Thanks.

Comment: @JGaines Can you give me upvote and can you pick my answer as accepted answer. I need reputation points :)

Comment: @MehmetMertYidiran If I can fully solve the issue from your answer then I will make yours accepted. I would upvote for the useful info, but it claims I need at least 15 reputation to upvote anything...

Comment: @JGaines I gave a lot of upvotes to you. I worked hard for this topic. I can not solve "sound playing 1-3 times" issue from there. Your main issue solved I think.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't output anything for me. manually executing the script does. kind of strange :/